# EE: Converting list to feature collection for export

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, feature-collection

I am attempting to export a list of some NDVI data to my Google Drive. However, I am unable to export the list (when using export.table.toDrive) to my drive, as I get an error warning that my collection must be a feature collection. Below is my sad attempt at doing so.

```
var time_1 = image;
```

The above variable is just a single-band image containing NDVI values in a .tif (uploaded to GEE as an asset)

```
var reduced = time_1.reduceRegion(
  {reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), scale: 275});

var extracted = reduced.get('b1')

var asList = ee.List(extracted); 

var funkshin = function(index) {
  var featurify = ee.Feature(index); 
  return featurify

var list_collect = asList.map(funkshin);
var collected = ee.FeatureCollection(list_collect)

print(collected);
```

When I execute the above code, I get a feature collection Error. it says the following:

> collection, argument 'features': Invalid type.
>
> Expected type: List Element.
>
> Actual type: List Float

Answer (score 1):

The items in the list are just numbers.  You can't just call that a feature because a) features have geometries, and b) feature properties have names.

A correct conversion would be:

```
var featurify = ee.Feature(null, {b1: index})
```

However, you can skip all that by just using ee.Reducer.toCollection in the first place, instead of toList.